# How to show right continuity for a df?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu$ is a Lebesgue Stieltjes measure on $(\mathbb{R},B_{\mathbb{R}})$. Define the function $F$ as follows:

$F(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \mu((0,x]) & x > 0 \\
      0 & x=0\\
      - \mu ((x,0]) & x<0 \\
   \end{cases}
$

We need to show that $F$ is a distribution function.

I have shown that $F$ is non-decreasing.

All I need to show is that $F$ is right continuous. That is now if we take a sequence $s_n \rightarrow 0^{+}$, we need to show that suppose for $x>0$, $\mu((0,x+s_n]) \rightarrow \mu((0,x])$. This is trivial if $s_n$ is a monotone sequence as we can directly use continuity from above. But $s_n$ here can be any arbitrary sequence going to $0$. So, how can we prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $\mu (-N,N) <\infty$ for all $N$.

This condition is satisfied by any L-S measure: see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/measure-probability-and/9781118831984/OEBPS/c04.htm

for the definition.

For $x>0$, $\mu((0,x+s_n]) = \mu((0,x]) +\mu((x,x+s_n])$  and the intervals $(x,x+s_n]$ decrease to the empty set as $s_n$ decreases to $0$. The proof for $x<0$ is similar.

Let $s_n \to 0+$ and $\epsilon >0$. Let $m=\{\inf f(y): y >x\}$. Then $ m \leq f(x+s_n )$ for all $n$. Next let $\epsilon>0$ and note that there exists $y>x$ such that $f(y) <m+\epsilon$. Now $f(x+s_n) \leq  f(y) <m+\epsilon$ for  $n$ sufficiently large by monotonicity of $f$. If you combine the two facts we just proves you can see that $f(x+s_n) \to m$ for any sequence $s_n \to 0+$.

Comment: But $s_n$ does not decrease monotonically to $0$. So, we cannot guarantee monotonicity of $(x,x+s_n]$. And so, we cannot use continuity from above directly

Comment: @MathsFreak If $f$ is an increasing function the limit of $f(x+s_n)$ is same for all sequences $s_n \to 0+$ (decreasing or not) and the value of the limit equals $\inf \{f(y): y >x\}$.  Can  you prove this fact?  I will add more details to my answer if you cannot prove this fact.

Comment: Yes, exactly I am stuck how to show this @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @MathsFreak I have edited my answer.

Comment: Look if $\mu$ was a finite measure then if $\lim A_n =A$ , then $\mu(\lim A_n) \rightarrow \mu(A)$ , regardless of the monotonicity of $A_n$ . But how do we do this for sigma finite measures like this one?

Comment: @MathsFreak you only  need the measure of every bounded interval to be finite. This is usually assumed in the definition of Lebesgue Stieltje's measure.

Comment: Ok, but even if that happens, I need the finiteness of sets like $\cup_{m=n}^{\infty} \mu(A_m)$ to complete the proof, which is not evident if $\mu$ is not a finite measure

Comment: @MathsFreak $(x,x+s_n) \subset (x,x+1)$ for $n$ large and finiteness of $\mu (x,x+1)$ is enough: if $A_n$ decreases to the empty set and $\mu (A_n) <\infty$ for some $n$ then $\mu (A_n) \to 0$.

Comment: @MathsFreak: To show right continuity of $F$ is enough to consider increasing or decreasing sequences of sets :$(0,x+s_n]$ with $x\geq0$ or $(x+s_n,0]$ for $x<0$, where $s_n\nearrow0$. Finiteness of $\mu$ is only used for the decreasing sequence. Finiteness of bounded sets is a given since $\mu$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure, which is finite on bounded intervals.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to consider for $s_n\searrow0$ and show that $\lim_nF(x+s_n)=F(x)$.

$$\bigcap_n(0,x+s_n]= (0,x]$$
for all $x\geq0$.

$$ \bigcup_n(x+s_n,0]=(x,0]$$
for all $x<0$.

Use the fact that $\mu$ is a Lebeusgue-Stieltjes measure, which imply that $\mu$ is finite in bounded sets. The rest is a well known result that says that $\mu(A_n)\nearrow\mu(A)$ when $A_n\nearrow A$ and $\mu(A_n)\searrow\mu(A)$ when $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ and $A_n\searrow A$.